What’s the punishment for offering a korban wrongly?
What's the punishment for offering a korban in an incorrect way?
For example as per Masechet Kinnim 1:1, you may not offer a bird olah below the hut ha-siqra (the red line that horizontally separates the upper and lower parts of the altar). What would be the punishment for offering it below the hut ha-siqra?

In Rambam הלכות מעשה הקרבנות

6:1 מצוות עשה לעשות העולה כמשפט
7:1 מצוות עשה לעשות החטאות כמצותן
9:1 מצוות עשה לעשות כל האשמות כמצוותו
13:1 מצוות עשה לעשות כל מנחה כמצותה

Based on that if something was modified from the way the Korban is supposed to be sacrificed, no physical punishment by Bais Din will be applied, given that it is only a מצות עשה that was transgressed, which doesn't carry a punishment.
Excluded from that is if a korban is done outside of the עזרה, which carries the punishment of כרת if done on purpose. A korban חטאת is brought if transgressed בשוגג.

@RabbiKaii, I didn't find the section talking about shelamim , still working on that.
